# Why does $digest() crash

Tags: angularjs

In the following AngularJS code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js" ></script>
  </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

      myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope)
      {
           // let's assume that scope was dependency injected as the $rootScope
           var scope = $rootScope;
           scope.name = 'misko';
           scope.counter = 0;

           scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue)
           {
             scope.counter = scope.counter + 1;
           });

           scope.$digest();

      }]);

  </script>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div id="divCool" ng-show="false">Cool</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

scope.$digest(); crashes but I don't know why. I took the code inside the controller straight from angularjs.org

Comment: Why are you calling scope.$digest()?

Comment: Code is from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason for calling `digest` in that context. Angular manages that for you. Actually, you hardly ever are going to need to use that function, but most commonly `apply`.

In this case, the code is taken from angular docs in a context of unit testing, where the scope needs to be refreshed by yourself for the assertions after setting up the test conditions.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why digest crashes.